# Can't connect to WebSocket server with fsockopen

Tags: php, websocket, fsockopen

Please, help me to connect WebSocket with php.

I try this code, but I've got 400 Bad Request

```
$fp = fsockopen("cs.money", 443, $errno, $errstr, 30);

if (!$fp) 
{
    echo "$errstr ($errno)<br />n";
} 
else
{
    $out = "GET / HTTP/1.1rnrn";
    ///Send data
    fwrite($fp, $out);

    ///Receive data - in small chunks :)
    while (!feof($fp)) 
    {
        echo fgets($fp, 128);
    }

    fclose($fp);
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I've solved my problem with js.

```
var WebSocket = require('ws');
var ws = new WebSocket('wss://cs.money/ws');
```